# ADB shell: How do I get a list of BroadcastReceivers that will receive BOOT_COMPLETED Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, adb, dumpsys

I am currently debugging an application that should auto-start after the device boots. To this end I have created a `BroadcastReceiver` and added it to my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.StartupBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This works all of the time on most devices. On one device however (an MXQ Pro set-top box) it only works most of the time. So far, I have not been able to find any patterns in when it works and when it does not.

**So, I would like to find out which BroadcastReceivers are actually, currently registered with the system to receive the BOOT_COMPLETED Intent.**

I played around a bit with

- `pm`: but this only tells me which packages *would like to* receive the Intent
- `dumpsys`: but its output is overwhelming and I don't know what to look for

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: tried `dumpsys activity -h`?

Comment: Ah, yes, I did look at the documentation. `dumpsys activity b` seemed promising, but I can find neither my package name nor the actual `BroadcastReceiver` in there, even on devices where everything works. There are hundreds of "ReceiverLists" each with their own ID, but nothing matches the output of, for example, `dumpsys package my.package.name` either. Hence the "overwhelming".

Comment: i just run `dumpsys package my.package.name` and got: `Receiver Resolver Table:
  Non-Data Actions:
      android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED:
        52b3eee0 my.package.name/.MyReceiver filter 52b3ef68
          Action: "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"`

Answer (score 24):

If you just need to confirm that some specific *receiver* was properly registered (i.e. you care only about receivers in some specific package you know name of) then just use `dumpsys package my.package.name` like *@pskink* suggested in the comments.

But if you indeed want to know all the receivers system-wide receiving some specific *intent* - since Android 7.0 you can use

```
adb shell cmd package query-receivers --brief -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Remove the `--brief` parameter if you want more details. And to list just the names:

```
adb shell cmd package query-receivers --components -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Comment: Is there also a way to get **all** receivers at once, not only the `BOOT_COMPLETED` ones.

Comment: @Alex P. How to check receiver without ACTION(explicit) is registered or not?